# How can I simulate single channel CAN network in CANoe without real ECUs connected on the bus?

Tags: simulation, can-bus, capl, canoe

I am planning to simulate a vehicle n/w on CANoe. How do I simulate two nodes to communicate each other and send acknowledge message to each other. I do not want to use a Y-cable because I will need the other channel on CANcase reserved.
So, I would like to use just single channel of CANcase and make this simulation work without acknowledgement error.
Kindly share your expert views on this scenario, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Network Hardware`, choose your channel and enable `TX Self ACK`.

[image: TX Self ACK Option]

Enabling this will make your HW VN Interface acknowledge their own messages and thus there will not be errors if there are no real ECUs on the bus.

Or you could use `Simulated Bus` mode in CANoe, which allows you to simulate your simulation nodes, without HW, in real time or with speed factor.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tomasz, you answer solved my problem. these small information are very useful. I hope to learn a lot more in using CANoe tool.